# using getText to get an Integer

Tags: java, swing, input, jtextarea

I am working on a program with in interface that uses textAreas in order to recieve user input and at one point when I use the getText() function it tells me that the variable that I am trying to declare with it, an integer, must be a string. Would there be any other way to change this or would there be another function that I would use to call in integer from a textArea?

Edit:

Sorry, I did leave out some code for an example.

```
public void SetStock(javax.swing.JTextArea textStock)
{
    Integer _textStock = textStock.getText();
}
public  Integer getTextStock()
{
    return _textStock;
}
```

This is the setter/getter that I am trying to use in order to use it within my main class.

Comment: Get the text then convert it to an integer.

Comment: Use a `JSpinner` with a `SpinnerNumberModel`.  Call [`SpinnerNumberModel.getValue()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SpinnerNumberModel.html#getValue%28%29) for an `Object` that should be `Integer` (presuming the number model started with int values).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the text, and then parse it as an integer using

```
int i = Integer.parseInt(myText.getText());
```

also, `Integer.parseInt` can throw an exception if the text is not a valid integer, so you might want to surround that in a try/catch block and catch the exception `NumberFormatException`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the *Integer.parseInt()* method to convert a *String* to an int, like this:

```
String text = textArea.getText();
int number = Integer.parseInt(text);
```

Keep in mind that if the text contains non-numerical characters an exception will be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you just have to parse it:

```
Integer myint = Integer.parseInt(textarea.getText());
```

But if my "textarea" you mean a multiline textbox, you will have to loop trough the lines and parse them.